# Transferring data between C# App and Web Server

Tags: c#, webserver

On start, my application makes a simple GET web-request to a webserver. Depending on the response from the server, the application may need to send another request to the same web server, which response has to contain **a block of html code**. The question is: How do I compress / minify the response (some html code) to reduce the bandwidth, without needing any 3-rd party libraries for my C# App to decompress the recieved data. I have tought only about base64 encoding (which is not compressing the data), are there any more productive ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, natively you have [GZip compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) in .NET. Besides that, you can use [other libraries](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sharpziplib/) to do the compression. Then, there's always making up your own compression scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Why not the standard gzip? Algorithm is in .net library.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the server to give you compressed data if it supports it :

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://your.server/url");
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip,deflate");

var webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
var responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();

if (webResponse.ContentEncoding.Contains("gzip", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
{
    responseStream = new GZipStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
}
else if (WebResponse.ContentEncoding.ToLower().Contains("deflate"))
{
    responseStream = new DeflateStream(responseStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);            
}

var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);

string html = reader.ReadToEnd();

webResponse.Close();
responseStream.Close();
```

Full details here : http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Jun/29/HttpWebRequest-and-GZip-Http-Responses